# screen shot is not displayed in extent report

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, extentreports

The screen shot is taken and stored in the folder. but its not displaying for the failed test.
displayed as corrupted image.

Java Code:

```
    public synchronized void onTestFailure(ITestResult result) {
                System.out.println((result.getMethod().getMethodName() + " failed!"));
                test.get().fail(MarkupHelper.createLabel(result.getName()+ " - Test failed due to below issue/error: ", ExtentColor.RED));
                test.get().fail(result.getThrowable());
                
                //Take screenshot and allow automatic saving of media files relative to the report
                //Extentreports log and screenshot operations for failed tests.
                try {
                    File src=((TakesScreenshot)driver).getScreenshotAs(OutputType.FILE);
    //          String base64Screenshot = "data:image/png;base64,"+((TakesScreenshot)driver).getScreenshotAs(OutputType.BASE64);
                    String path=prop.getProperty("Screenshot_Folder")+System.currentTimeMillis()+".png";
                    File destination=new File(path);
                    FileUtils.copyFile(src, destination);
                    
                    test.get().fail("Below is Screen Shot of Error Page/Pop-up: ", MediaEntityBuilder.createScreenCaptureFromPath(path).build());
                    //test.get().fail("Below is Screen Shot of Error Page/Pop-up: ", MediaEntityBuilder.createScreenCaptureFromBase64String(base64Screenshot).build());
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    System.out.println("Screen-capture has been taken but not attached to Extent report");
                }
    
            }
```

below is the property file.

```
AutomationReport_Folder = D://Shared//V1core_automation
ExtentReport_Folder = D://Shared//V1core_automation//ExtentReports//
Screenshot_Folder = D://Shared//V1core_automation//ExtentReports//Screenshots//
```

Method for screen shot

public static String getScreenshot(WebDriver driver)
{

```
        TakesScreenshot ts=(TakesScreenshot) driver;
        File src=ts.getScreenshotAs(OutputType.FILE);

        String path=System.getProperty("user.dir")+"/Screenshots/"+System.currentTimeMillis()+".png";

        File destination=new File(path);

        try 
        {
            FileUtils.copyFile(src, destination);
        } catch (IOException e) 
        {
            System.out.println("Capture Failed "+e.getMessage());
        }

        return path;

    }
```

Comment: Do you have the report and the screenshots stored in the same directory?

Comment: yes i have in same directory

Comment: How defined your "Screenshot_Folder" property?

Comment: i have created the property file, in which i have defined the folder path for screen shot and report. i have attached same in question for the reference.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar requirement to store screenshots in base64 as reports will be shared with multiple stakeholders across my team. The following solution worked well for me.

Screenshot.java

```
public static String getScreenshot(WebDriver driver) {
        String screenshotBase64 = ((TakesScreenshot) driver).getScreenshotAs(OutputType.BASE64);
        return screenshotBase64;
    }
```

TestListener.java

```
@Override
    public void onTestFailure(ITestResult result) {
        test.fail("Test case Failed");
        test.fail("Failed step: ",MediaEntityBuilder.createScreenCaptureFromBase64String("data:image/png;base64,"+Screenshot.getScreenshot(driver)).build());
        test.fail(result.getThrowable());
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace this line in  your code:

```
test.get().fail("Below is Screen Shot of Error Page/Pop-up: ", MediaEntityBuilder.createScreenCaptureFromPath(path).build());
```

With

```
MediaEntityBuilder.addScreenCaptureFromPath(path, result.getMethod().getMethodName());
```

and see it works.